# Flask for Python - architectural question regarding the system

Tags: python, flask

I've been using Django and Django passes in a request object to a view when it's run. It looks like (from first glance) in Flask the application owns the request and it's imported (as if it was a static resource). I don't understand this and I'm just trying to wrap my brain around WSGI and Flask, etc. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Flask request is a thread-safe global, so you actually do import it:

```
from flask import request
```

I'm not sure this feature is related to WSGI as other WSGI micro-frameworks do pass request as a view function argument. "Global" request object is a feature of Flask. Flask also encourages to store user's data which is valid for a single request in a similar object called flask.g:

> To share data that is valid for one
>   request only from one function to
>   another, a global variable is not good
>   enough because it would break in
>   threaded environments. Flask provides
>   you with a special object that ensures
>   it is only valid for the active
>   request and that will return different
>   values for each request. In a
>   nutshell: it does the right thing,
>   like it does for request and session.